# Contradiction in polynomial equation.

Tags: polynomials

I am getting a contradiction in solving this question.

Solve the equation

$$(x^2-3x+3)^2 -3(x^2-3x+3) +3 = x$$

Here is what I did.

$$f(x) = x^2-3x+3$$

Then, the equation becomes,

$$[f(x)]^2 -3f(x) + 3 = x\implies f(f(x)) = x$$

So, I put $x=0$,
And the equation became

$$f(f(0))= 0\implies f(3) =0$$

But, $$f(3) = 3\neq 0$$

What is the mistake here ?

Comment: $f(f(x))=x$ is true only when $x$ is a root of  the equation. Remember that you are assuming that $(x^2-3x+3)^2-3(x^2-3x+3)+3=x$ is true to obtain this equation. The above equation is satisfied only by the roots of that equation, not for all $x$. If you are getting a contradiction by putting $x=0$, then it's  because $0$ is not a root of your equation, which is easy  to see  because plugging in gives you $3=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: This is not a "functional equation." It is just an equation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Isn't $f(f(x)) = x$ a functional equation ?

Comment: No, a "functional equation" is one where you are solving for a function. You are solving for $x$ - you know what $f$ is. @user230452

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ok. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand what you are doing. You get some solutions of $f(f(x)) = x$ from the easier $f(x) = x.$ It is easy enough to solve that, the numbers are $1,3$ as in
$$ f(1) = 1, $$
$$  f(3) = 3.$$
This gives two easy solutions to $f(x) = x.$ Once you have $f(x) = x,$ you get $f(f(x)) = f(x) = x$ as well. There could be others, or these could have higher multiplicity...

One quick conclusion: you want the roots of the quartic $g(x) =f(f(x)) - x.$ Well, we know that $g(x)$ is divisible by $x^2 - 4x + 3.$ Find the quotient, then find those new roots from the quadratic formula. Yep, $g(x) = (x-3)(x-1)^3.$

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why solving $f(f(x)) = x$ is equivalent to solving $f(x) = x$ ? This is tripping me up. I am not able to understand this step.

Comment: @user230452 not equivalent. If you find some $a$ with $f(a) = a,$ then we see that $f(f(a)) = f(a) = a,$ so this $a$ is also an answer to your original question. Such values, $f(a) = a,$ are called fixed points of $f,$ sometimes written as fixpoint.

Comment: @user230452 meanwhile, could you please get some graph paper, write out $f(f(x))$ which is of degree four, graph $y = f(f(x)),$ also draw in $y=x.$